# Show label and sliding checkbox on same line

Tags: html, css, checkbox

In my HTML page, I am trying to align a label and a sliding checkbox on the same line. My code is given below (the sliding checkbox code was taken from another post here).

```css
.ondisplay {
  display: inline-block;
}
/* SLIDE THREE */

.slideThree {
  width: 80px;
  height: 26px;
  background: #333;
  margin: 10px auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.slideThree:after {
  content: 'OFF';
  font: 12px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}
.slideThree:before {
  content: 'ON';
  font: 12px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #00bf00;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.slideThree label {
  display: block;
  width: 34px;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background: #fcfff4;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fcfff4', endColorstr='#b3bead', GradientType=0);
}
.slideThree input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  left: 43px;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="ondisplay">
  <div><strong>Test: </strong>
  </div>
  <div class="slideThree">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="slideThree" name="check" checked/>
    <label for="slideThree"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

With these, the label "Test" and the slider are appearing one below the other left-aligned. I need them to appear on the same line, first the label then the slider. I tried `display: inline` but it didn't work. I am still kind of new with CSS. Can anyone help please?

**EDIT:** This was the fiddle I referred to - http://jsfiddle.net/CXn3v/

Comment: The label `test` is a normal div, which is displayed as a block and will occupy the whole line. I'm mainly curious why you don't use the actual `label` element that is already in your HTML. That would make the document at least more semantically correct.

Comment: @GolezTrol I tried that already. That empty label is for the slider, not the checkbox itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following CSS rule.

```
.ondisplay > div {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
.ondisplay {
  display: inline-block;
}

.ondisplay > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
/* SLIDE THREE */

.slideThree {
  width: 80px;
  height: 26px;
  background: #333;
  margin: 10px auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.slideThree:after {
  content: 'OFF';
  font: 12px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}
.slideThree:before {
  content: 'ON';
  font: 12px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #00bf00;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.slideThree label {
  display: block;
  width: 34px;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background: #fcfff4;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fcfff4', endColorstr='#b3bead', GradientType=0);
}
.slideThree input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  left: 43px;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="ondisplay">
  <div><strong>Test: </strong>
  </div>
  <div class="slideThree">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="slideThree" name="check" checked/>
    <label for="slideThree"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, I have added a class `label` to the `<div class="label"><strong>Test: </strong>
      </div>` and assigned it `display:inline-block` property to it and `slideThree` DIV as well.

Please check below snippet :

```css
.ondisplay {
  display: inline-block;
}
/* SLIDE THREE */
.label{ display: inline-block;}
.slideThree {

  width: 80px;
  height: 26px;
  background: #333;
  margin: 10px auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
   display: inline-block;
}
.slideThree:after {
  content: 'OFF';
  font: 12px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}
.slideThree:before {
  content: 'ON';
  font: 12px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #00bf00;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.slideThree label {
  display: block;
  width: 34px;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background: #fcfff4;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fcfff4', endColorstr='#b3bead', GradientType=0);
}
.slideThree input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  left: 43px;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="ondisplay">
  <div class="label"><strong>Test: </strong>
  </div>
  <div class="slideThree">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="slideThree" name="check" checked/>
    <label for="slideThree"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The checkbox shifted to the right, but still remained on a different line.:-(

Comment: can you run the code snippet, label and on/off button is in single line.